# Suppose $G$ is a finite simple group whose order is divisible by $p^2$. Show there is no subgroup with index $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

> Suppose $G$ is a finite simple group such that $p^2$ divides $|G|$ for some prime $p$. Show there is no subgroup of $G$ of index $p$.

We can write the order of $G$ as $|G|=p^2m$. I want to use the third Sylow theorem, but there is no restriction that $p$ does not divide $m$. So, I rewrote the order as $|G|=p^nm_1$ where $n\geq2$ and $p$ does not divide $m_1$. But, I don't know how to convert this into a proof showing the index of a subgroup can't be $p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $p$, left multiplication on cosets $G/H$ gives a non-trivial homomorphism $G \to S_p$. This must be injective as $G$ is simple. But $p^2$ doesn't divide $p!$ the order of $S_p$.

Comment: Thank you! But, why does $G$ being simple imply that the homomorphism is injective?

Comment: @JellyHops Because the kernel of any homomorphism is a normal subgroup of the domain Group.

Comment: My understanding is this: I have a list of the cosets $\{ H, g_1H, \ldots, g_{p-1}H\}$. Then left-multiplying by some element $x\in G$ permutes this list hence the homomorphism. Doesn't this already mean it's injective? Because if $xg_aH=xg_bH$, then $g_aH=g_bH$.

Comment: @JellyHops no, we definitely need to use that $G$ is simple here, via the argument that Lawrence gave. Injectivity here means that if we have $xg_iH=g_iH$ for all $i$, then $x=e$

Comment: Ohh, I see. So it's (in a way) a step up? I was redundantly saying that each permutation is injective. But, we actually need to say that this left-multiplication is injective(?) That if $x_1\neq x_2$, then $x_1g_i H$ is a different permutation from $x_2g_i H$?

Comment: @JellyHops we need to have that if $x_1 \neq x_2$, then the permutation $g_i H \mapsto x_1g_i H$ is not the same as the permutation $g_iH \mapsto x_2g_iH$ which means that $x_1g_i H \neq x_2g_i H$ for some $i$

Comment: In fact, by essentially the same argument, one can prove that if p is the smallest prime dividing the order of G, a subgroup of index p must be normal in G.